# ONFOCUS/ ONBLUR submits the default value instead of an empty value if nothing entered in INPUT box

Tags: php, forms, default-value, onblur, onfocus

I have replaced the default 'value' with some dynamic actions instead. There is a default value in the input box, user clicks and default value is deleted. User leaves and inputs nothing, default value re-appears. So far so good.

The problem is that whenever the user submits the form and leaves the name field empty, I get the default value as a result instead of either nothing or an empty field.

```
<input style="width:95%;" type="text" name="email" 
onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" 
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
value="<?php echo $entry_email; ?>" maxlength="27" size="50" />
```

I've been reading S.O. for a while and say other options like onclick instead of onfocus. Also, onsubmit and then everybody also suggest changing the code to handle that function and that's where it all blends together in a big ball of confusion. I know this question has been asked over and over, but they all involve js code updates.

Am I crazy thinking that my code above can be modified a little bit so check that the default value is either filled out or blank, but not submit default value?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the submit button your text input triggers the onblur event first, then the form submits.  So you are submitting the default value.  Check for the default matching the value on the form submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate html and js code. Use jquery, it's easy to learn

```
<input style="width:95%;" type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $entry_email; ?>" maxlength="27" size="50" />
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript">         
$('#email').blur(function() {
          $('#email').val(defaultValue);
        });
</script>
```

And check whether user's email value is equal to default value, then stop form submission.

Comment: Your example is great, I can understand that. So I changed my code and nothing happens. If I manually delete the default value and I leave the box (onblur) the box stays empty as well? The platform I use already makes use of jquery.min.js so I tried it with the call to the script and without, still nothing changed?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `placeholder` inside `input` tag.

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter Email">
```

Comment: however doesn't provide dynamism as of `onFocus` and `onBlur`.